# C++ anonymous variables

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Why won't this work?

```
 0. #define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
 1. 
 2. #define VAR_LINE(x) \
 3.     int CONCAT(_anonymous, __LINE__) = x
 4. 
 5. #define VAR_LINE2(x) \
 6.     int _anonymous ## x = 1
 7.
 8. int main()
 9. {
10.     VAR_LINE(1);
11.     VAR_LINE(1);
12.     VAR_LINE(1);
13.     VAR_LINE2(__LINE__);
14. }
```

The result from the above macro expansion

```
int _anonymous__LINE__ = 1;
int _anonymous__LINE__ = 1;
int _anonymous__LINE__ = 1;
int _anonymous13 = 1;
```

It would be convenient if I didn't have to write that `__LINE__` macro as an argument.

I'm thinking the problem is pretty clear. I want to be able to generate anonymous variables so that this macro doesn't fail with redefinition error when declaring several variables within the same scope. My idea was to use the predefined `__LINE__` macro because no variable will ever be declared on the same line like this. But the macro expansion troubles me, can you help?

## Update: Correct answer

Thanks to Luc Touraille. However, there was a tiny problem with the suggested solution. There has to be whitespace between the operands and the ## operator (apparently the standard says otherwise but the the PS3 flavoured GCC would not expand the macro properly if there were no whitespace between the operator and operands).

```
#define _CONCAT(x,y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x,y) _CONCAT(x,y)
```

The VAR_LINE macro now yields:

```
int _anonymous10 = 1;
int _anonymous11 = 1;
int _anonymous12 = 1;
```

This has been verified to work under Win32 (Visual Studio 2008), XBOX360 (Xenon) and PS3.

Comment: It's not, I understand why you might think that. Anonymous variables have many uses. I need the duration of objects to be in scope. Without a name, be it anonymous or not they will simply created and right after destroys that same object.

Comment: But that means you're relying on side-effects. If a method requires a certain object to exist, pass the object as a parameter. Make the dependancy explicit, it will make maintenance easier. I guess you must be using a singleton style interface to access the anonymous objects?

Comment: To expand on the whole 'anonymous is bad' - someone in the future will forget to create the object and won't realise its importance until the program crashes and even then won't be totally sure why. By naming the object and passing it as a parameter will catch the error at compile time.

Comment: You also have threading issues - what if two threads create the same anonymous object - which one should be used?

Comment: There's no threading issue and the anonymous objects are not accessible. They sole purpose here is ensure object life-time and that requires a name. Be it anonymous or not. The example does not convey in anyway what I'm trying to do and so I understand it can be confusing.

Comment: This is not fundamentally wrong. C++11 should have added a keyword for anonymous variables so we don't have to use macros. Perhaps something like: int auto; Allows use of auto keyword in place of variable name. Yes, this allows such things as "auto auto = 5.f;"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add a level of indirection so that `__LINE__` will be expanded:

```
#define _CONCAT_(x,y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x,y) _CONCAT_(x,y)

#define VAR_LINE(x) int CONCAT(_anonymous, __LINE__) = x
```

Comment: Here's the deal, there's a problem with your suggested solution. There has to be whitespace between the operands and the ## operator. Your suggested solution should read #define _CONCAT_(x,y) x ## y.

Comment: Well this is weird, the standard specifically states that "Space around the # and ## tokens in the macro definition is optional." (16.3.5 par.6). Anyway, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Indeed it is, I checked this with people at work as well. Apparently the PS3 flavoured GCC would not expand the macro properly if there were no whitespace between the operator and operands.