# Why is it allowed to have a declaration without a name?

Tags: c++, c++11, declaration, definition

While reading the standard, I was really surprised to see that actually, the name is optional in a declaration:

```
struct Magic {};
int main() {
  int; // well-formed
  Magic; // well-formed
}
```

For those interested to read the standard, it's because in a *simple-declaration*, the *init-declarator-list* is optional. Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/HXdRvM).

And so I really want to know why this is allowed. Why would I ever want to do that? It really makes no sense to me. My reasoning is that, because if it makes no sense, why allow it?

Comment: @ChrisSprague so, "because that's the same grammar for function parameters and it's useful there"?

Comment: @ChrisSprague That would make sense. But the *parameter-declaration-clause* already uses a separate grammar altogether (*abstract-declarator*) together with *declator*. There is no need for that to be the case for *declarator*, I gather.

Comment: A user defined object could do some work in constructor/destructor (eg create a database transaction).

Comment: @manni66 That's not the case here, no objects are created.

Comment: Related: `struct {something};` counts as a declaration declaring nothing too.

Comment: I wonder why the standard still allows this? Maybe so old broken code is thill allowed to compile?

Comment: `-pedantic-errors` is your friend.

Comment: That demo doesn’t show it’s well-formed. For one thing, I think Clang only claims to be conforming with `-pedantic`. For another, both GCC and Clang say warnings count as diagnostic messages, and all the standard requires for ill-formed code is a diagnostic (usually); the compiler can still emit a program if it wants.

Comment: I believe they are called or referred to as anonymous objects. Also see [What is an Anonymous Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5330287/608639), [Is it possible to pass an “unnamed” variable to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3394797/608639), [Passing an anonymous variable by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19875697/608639), [C++ anonymous variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461062/608639), etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (7 Declarations)

> 5 In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be
>   omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration (7.2),
>   that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a
>   *class-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier* with a *class-key* (9.1),
>   or an *enum-specifier*....

Thus this code

```
int main() {
  int; // well-formed
  Magic; // well-formed
}
```

is ill-formed.

Moreover formally these ill-formed declarations are definitions according to the paragraph #2 of the section *3.1 Declarations and definitions* and obviously as such do not make sense.

Comment: Nice one. It's funny how most people just believed the OP and didn't try to compile the code with proper flags.

Comment: I was looking in declarators for something like this, did not expect this to be in declarations :) Thanks

Comment: This explanation only goes so far because (what's supposed to be) the *init-declarator-list* might not be completely omitted. Rakete1111's comment to the question applies in this case, instead, a *declarator* is required (and not an *abstract-declarator*), which must ultimately contain an *id-expression*. Example, `*` is a valid *abstract-declarator*, but not a valid *declarator*, so `int *;` is not a valid *simple-declaration*.